# I have 10000 integers from a file, How do I make each work thread responsible for 1000 integers, like first thread for the first 1000 and so on?

Tags: c, multithreading

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>


int inparray[10000]; //global integer array.
void *AVERAGE(void *parama){
    //sum divided by the counts
    
    float *sum = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float));
    *sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        *sum += inparray[i];
    }

    *sum = *sum/1000;
    return (void *)sum;

}
//compute the sum for each thread.
void *sum(void *param) { 
    int *sum = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        *sum += inparray[i];
    }
    return (void *)sum;

}

void *square_root_of_the_sum(void *parama){
    //square root of the sum of the squares
    float *sum = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float));
    *sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        *sum += inparray[i]*inparray[i];
    }
    *sum = sqrt(*sum);
    return (void *)sum;

}



void *computation_child(void *param) {
//each thread create additional 3 computation threads
pthread_t tid[3];

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 
    if (pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, AVERAGE, NULL) != 0) { 

        printf("Error creating thread.\n");
         exit(0);

    

    }
    if (pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, sum, NULL) != 0) {
        printf("Error creating thread.\n");
          exit(0);

    }
    if (pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, square_root_of_the_sum, NULL) != 0) {
        printf("Error creating thread.\n");
         exit(0);

    }
    if (pthread_join(tid[i], NULL)!=0) { //join when finishes
    printf("Error joining thread.\n");
    exit(0);
}
}
}






int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) { 

//read the integers from the input file and store it to integer array
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
if (fp == NULL) { //check if we have the right file.
printf("Error opening file");
exit(1);
}
int i = 0;
while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &inparray[i]) != EOF) { // while the file is not empty
i++;
}
fclose(fp); 



pthread_t tid[10]; 

for ( int a = 0; a < 10; a++) {//worker threads
    
    if (pthread_create(&tid[a], NULL, computation_child, NULL) != 0) {
      printf("Error creating thread.\n");
      return 1;
    }

    if (pthread_join(tid[a], NULL)!=0) { //join when finishes
    printf("Error joining thread.\n");
    return 2;
}
```

I have 10000 integers from a file, How do I make each worker thread responsible for 1000 integers, like the first thread for the first 1000 and the second thread responsible for 1001-2000 and so on the work threads do not do the computations, the computation_child will create addition threads to do the computations. Do I need to use an index or a pointer?

this is my output:
Thread 0 created.
Average is 497.431000
Sum is 497431
Square root of the sum is 18182.789062
Thread 1 created.
Average is 497.431000
Sum is 497431
Square root of the sum is 18182.789062
Thread 2 created.
Average is 497.431000
Sum is 497431
Square root of the sum is 18182.789062
Thread 3 created.
Average is 497.431000
Sum is 497431
Square root of the sum is 18182.789062
Thread 4 created.
Average is 497.431000
Sum is 497431
Square root of the sum is 18182.789062
Thread 5 created.
Average is 497.431000
Sum is 497431
Square root of the sum is 18182.789062
Thread 6 created.
Average is 497.431000
Sum is 497431
Square root of the sum is 18182.789062
Thread 7 created.
Average is 497.431000
Sum is 497431
Square root of the sum is 18182.789062
Thread 8 created.
Average is 497.431000
Sum is 497431
Square root of the sum is 18182.789062
Thread 9 created.
Average is 497.431000
Sum is 497431
Square root of the sum is 18182.789062

Comment: Starting a thread works, from your perspective,  just a function call so you can pass the array and index or a just the pointer (via a single pointer arg).

Comment: Thread 0 created. 
Average is 497.431000
Sum is 497431
Square root of the sum is 18182.789062
Thread 1 created.
Average is 497.431000
Sum is 497431
Square root of the sum is 18182.789062
Thread 2 created.
Average is 497.431000 
Sum is 497431
Square root of the sum is 18182.789062
Thread 3 created.
Average is 497.431000
Sum is 497431
Square root of the sum is 18182.789062  and continue 
how do i fix this so each thread can work on different segments?

Comment: Update your question with new data (instead of a comment).  You call `ARITHMETIC_AVERAGE` but it's not defined in your code sample.

Comment: You should post working code, ideally, a [mre].  Try the answer below and let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

I would pass a pointer and a length to your function:

```
struct job {
  int *a;
  size_t a_len;
};
```

Then when calling your function, say `square_root_of_the_sum`:

```
pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, square_root_of_the_sum, &(struct job) { &inparray[1000 * i], 1000 })
```

In your function, square_root_of_the_sum, you cast the void * to the right type.  This also eliminates the global variable which is especially problematic in threaded code.

```
void *square_root_of_the_sum(void *parama){
    struct job *job = parama;
    float *sum = malloc(sizeof(*sum));
    *sum = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < job->a_len; i++) {
        *sum += job->a[i] * job->a[i];
    }
    *sum = sqrt(*sum);
    return (void *) sum;
}
```

Also these functions are very similar, so maybe refactor them to eliminate the duplicated code.